# Problems with Grants Management

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, nonprofit-starter-pack

i tried to install the Grants Management pack in a trailhead sandbox,
I have active My Domain and the Digital Experience but i get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grants Management is a licensed product. You cannot install it in a Trailhead Playground.

However, the installer should have presented a clear error message. I will work with the team to have this corrected.